# Неповторяемый факт из списка

Tags: python, python-3.x

Есть список интересных фактов. Надо сделать так, чтобы они не повторялись.

```
import random

sport = ['В футболе желтая и красная карточка появились в 1970 году.',
         'Джанни Инфантино является девятым президентом FIFA.']

question = input('Выберите категорию: ')

if question == '1':
    question = random.choice(sport)
    print(question)
```

Я попробовал удалить через `del sport(question)` и `sport.pop(question)`. Но ничего не помогает.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас не получается потому, что функции `pop` и `del` в качестве аргумента принимают индекс элемента списка, а вы даете ему конкретный элемент. Используйте метод `remove`

```
import random

sport = ['В футболе желтая и красная карточка появились в 1970 году.',
         'Джанни Инфантино является девятым президентом FIFA.']

question = input('Выберите категорию: ')


if question == '1':
    question = random.choice(sport)
    print(question)  # В футболе желтая и красная карточка появились в 1970 году.
    sport.remove(question)


print(sport)    # ['Джанни Инфантино является девятым президентом FIFA.']
```

Предложенными Вами функциями в данном случае можно пользоваться, например, так:
`sport.pop(sport.index(question))` или `del sport[sport.index(question)]`